# "Access Violation Reading Location" with Vertex Buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I am trying to convert the following piece of code into one that uses a vertex buffer:

```
glBegin (GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2fv (&_vertex[ci->index_list[7]].uv.x);
glVertex3fv (&_vertex[ci->index_list[7]].position.x);
glVertex3fv (&_vertex[ci->index_list[5]].position.x);
glVertex3fv (&_vertex[ci->index_list[3]].position.x);
glVertex3fv (&_vertex[ci->index_list[1]].position.x);
glEnd ();
```

My faulty code partly looks like this:

```
GLfloat * p = (GLfloat *) malloc(sizeof(GLfloat)*14);
//Memcopies vertices into p pointer
memcpy(&p[counter+0], &_vertex[ci->index_list[7]].uv.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*2);
memcpy(&p[counter+2], &_vertex[ci->index_list[7]].position.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);
memcpy(&p[counter+5], &_vertex[ci->index_list[5]].position.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);
memcpy(&p[counter+8], &_vertex[ci->index_list[3]].position.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);
memcpy(&p[counter+11], &_vertex[ci->index_list[1]].position.x, sizeof(GLfloat)*3);

glGenBuffers(1, &vboId1);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboId1);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*14, p, GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(GLfloat)*14, (GLfloat*)0); 
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0,  2+(GLfloat*)0);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 1);

glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

However, I get an "Access violation reading location" error on the glDrawArrays line.  Any ideas what could be wrong here?  I am very new to OpenGL/graphics and pretty sure I'm messing up something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not going to work. Immediate mode allowed you to omit respecifying unchanged attributes between vertices. But with vertex arrays, you cannot do that. What you currently do is telling the GL that it finds the TexCoords of the i-th vertex at byte offset 14*sizeof(GLfloat)*i in the buffer. For the first vertex, it will work, but for the second, you try to access data beyond the end of the buffer.

You have to duplicate that data, so that every vertex has exactly the same attributes, in the same layout. Basically, you need one vertex array per attribute, with one entry for **every** vertex, no matter it the value did change or not.

Better view a vertex as not just the position (specified by the `glVertex` command), but the complete n-tupel of relevant attributes. If *any* single component of *any* attribute differs, it is not to be considered the same vertex anymore.